# Why does kendo UI break when extending Array.prototype?

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-ui, prototype

I have an existing complex page with a bunch of kendo controls on it.
One of those controls is a treeview.

When I add this to my page ...

```
Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= this.length) {
        var k = new_index - this.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) { this.push(undefined); }
    }
    this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
};
```

... and expand 2 levels deep in to my tree view, i get an exception ...

```
VM25771:3 Uncaught TypeError: item.level is not a function
    at eval (eval at compile (kendo.all.js:194), <anonymous>:3:222)
    at Object.eval [as itemElement] (eval at compile (kendo.all.js:194), <anonymous>:3:244)
    at Object.eval [as item] (eval at compile (kendo.all.js:194), <anonymous>:3:459)
    at init._renderItem (kendo.all.js:75601)
    at init._insertNode (kendo.all.js:75004)
    at init._appendItems (kendo.all.js:75132)
    at init.refresh (kendo.all.js:75228)
    at init.d (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:124)
    at init._process (kendo.all.js:6938)
```

... i figured, maybe I had done something that kendo does, so i removed the proto method from my page and put a watch in "Array.prototype" ... no mention of a move function is listed.

I then figured maybe there's some internal thing that's not showing up so I renamed my prototype function to something random like this ...

```
Array.prototype.foobar = function (old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= this.length) {
        var k = new_index - this.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) { this.push(undefined); }
    }
    this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
};
```

... and the problem came back.

Does anyone know what might cause this?